# How do I populate a ModelChoiceField from two Models

Tags: django, python-3.x, forms, model

In my Form I want to populate a ModelChoiceField with Data from two Models.

How can I change the queryset that it contains the Objects of two different models?

My approach was to pack the querysets in a list. But that don't seems to be the right container for the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can use a ModelChoiceField with two different models, because you cannot have a queryset composed by two different models.

You'd better try to use [ChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield), which accepts a choices parameter with a list of tuples.

Say you have two models in models.py like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Model2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

You can create a Form like this in forms.py:

```
from django import forms

from .models import Model1, Model2

class MultipleModelChoiceForm(forms.Form):
    select = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MultipleModelChoiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        choices = []
        for obj1 in Model1.objects.all():
            choices.append((obj1.name, obj1.description))
        for obj2 in Model2.objects.all():
            choices.append((obj2.name, obj2.description))
        self.fields['select'].choices = choices
```

Note that choices are defined in the *__init__* of the form, to have the select field updated with all records in *Model1* and *Model2* when you create an instance of the form.

Comment: This works - kind of. If I add another Item to the Model the choices aren't updated just when I restart the server the new choices are populated into the field.

Comment: The provided example code **works**. The choices are populated in the `__init__` method of the form, so they are "refreshed" every time a form is created. You don't need to restart the server to see new instances.